# Local type as template arguments in C++

Tags: c++, templates

This is my code

```
#include <vector>
template <typename T, template<typename> class C = std::vector >
struct FooBar
{
   /*codez*/
};
template<typename T>
struct Global{};

int main()
{
   struct Local{};  
   FooBar<Local,Global> k;
}
```

This is the error that I get

`template argument for ‘template<class T, template<class> class C> struct FooBar’ uses local type ‘main()::Local’`

Which part of the standard says that this is wrong? I am using gcc 4.5.1. How can make this code work?

Comment: Are you compiling with the `--std=c++0x` option?

Comment: No I ain't using that option.

Comment: Ah, that ability doesn't come standard until C++0x.  See N2657 ( http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2657.htm ).  Just add that option and g++ will be happy with you.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Local_classes : "local classes could not be used as template arguments
(until C++11)
"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Which part of the standard says that this is wrong?

That would be §14.3.1/2 from the 2003 C++ Standard:

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a *template-argument* for a template *type-parameter*.

---

> How can make this code work?

Don't use a local type as a template argument.

Note that this restriction has been lifted in C++11, so using that language standard you are able to use a local type as a template argument.

Comment: I used `-std=c++0x` option and the code works. However if I use `FooBar<Local> k;` instead of `FooBar<Local,Global> k;` I get some errors. What's wrong with `FooBar<Local> k`?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that g++ supports that feature.  As for the problem with `FooBar<Local>`, it is because `std::vector` is not a valid template template argument for `template <typename> class` because `std::vector` isn't declared as `std::vector<T>`, it's declared as `std::vector<T, Alloc>`.

Comment: @Ron: `std::vector` has _two_ template arguments. So, `template <typename T, template<typename, typename> class C = std::vector>
 struct FooBar { .. };` See it working [here](http://www.ideone.com/9FQZP).

Answer (score 8):

14.3.1/2

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

Try compiling your code with `-std=c++0x` option (gcc 4.5.1). C++0x lifts the restriction and so you can use a local type as  template argument.