# How to determine if a path exists between 2 vertices in BGL

Tags: c++, graph, dijkstra, boost-graph

I want to use the Boost Graph Library to decide if there is a path between 2 nodes on an directed unweighted graph.

Therefore I try to use either Breath-First-Search or Dijkstra but I got confused by all these parameter lists.

What is the simplest way to create a function like this:

```
bool isPath(src,dest);
```

with BGL?

Comment: I think BFS is the simplest way to do it. Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470566/how-to-traverse-graph-in-boost-use-bfs). You need only implement `discover_vertex`.

Answer (score 2):

BFS/DFS is the simplest way. I'll sketch up DFS solution because it's less memory hungry.

Presuming you have adjacency matrix `adj` of size `N x N` (`N` being number of vertices in a graph) with:

1. `1` in `adj[i][j]` if you have edge going from `i` vertex to `j` vertex,
2. `0` otherwise.

In that case you could have something like this:

```
// doing DFS...
bool isPath(int src, int dest) {
  bool visited[N] = {false};
  visited[src] = true;
  std::stack<int> next;
  next.push(src);

  while(!next.empty()) {
    int cv = next.top();
    next.pop();

    for (int nv = 0; nv < N; ++nv) {
      if (!visited[nv] && adj[cv][nv] == 1) {
        visited[nv] = true;
        next.push(nv);
      }
    }
  }
  // dest was reached from src?
  return visited[dest];
}
```