# How do I create a queue of traversed vertex using boost graph library breadth-first search?

Tags: c++, boost, breadth-first-search

I would like to use boost graph library breadth first search to return a queue of vertex visited when starting on node 1.  I read the documentation but still am having trouble understanding how to implement this.

The result below would return a queue in the order: 1,2,3,4 or 1,3,2,4

```cpp
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, unsigned int> EdgeWeightProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, 
                              boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty> Graph;

//create graph and add edge
Graph g;
boost::add_edge(1,2,6,g);
boost::add_edge(2,3,6,g);
boost::add_edge(3,1,6,g);
boost::add_edge(3,4,6,g);

//Perform breadth first using boost and return result in a queue.
```

Comment: There are examples abound for using Boost's built-in BFS visitor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470566/how-to-traverse-graph-in-boost-use-bfs . Use the visitor, and when visiting each node, just enqueue the node ID to the back of the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boost graph library documentation defines a [BFS Visitor concept](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/BFSVisitor.html) which states

> Users can define a class with the BFS Visitor interface and pass an object of the class to `breadth_first_search()`, thereby augmenting the actions taken during the graph search.

based on this and the [`bfs.cpp` example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/example/bfs.cpp) the preferred method to accomplish what you are asking is to subclass either `boost::visitor` or `boost::default_bfs_visitor` and override one or several of

- `initialize_vertex`
- `discover_vertex`
- `examine_vertex`
- `examine_edge`
- `tree_edge`
- `non_tree_edge`
- `gray_target`
- `black_target`
- `finish_vertex`

For your use case I would say it is most appropriate to subclass `boost::default_bfs_visitor` and override `discover_vertex`:

> `discover_vertex(s, g)`
>
> > Invoked when a vertex is encountered for the first time. `s` is An object of type `boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor` and `g` is an object of type `Graph`.

Here is an example of exactly how to do that, with appropriate handling of a `std::queue` object to record the vertices.

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>

typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, unsigned int> EdgeWeightProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, 
                              boost::no_property, EdgeWeightProperty> Graph;

class BFSVisitor : public boost::default_bfs_visitor {
public:    
    BFSVisitor(std::queue<Graph::vertex_descriptor>& _v) : visited(_v){}
    void discover_vertex(Graph::vertex_descriptor s, const Graph &g) {
         visited.push(s); 
    }
    std::queue<Graph::vertex_descriptor>& visited;
};

int main() {
    Graph g;
    boost::add_edge(0,1,6,g);
    boost::add_edge(1,2,6,g);
    boost::add_edge(2,3,6,g);
    boost::add_edge(3,1,6,g);
    boost::add_edge(3,4,6,g);

    Graph::vertex_descriptor s = *(boost::vertices(g).first);
    std::queue<Graph::vertex_descriptor> q;
    BFSVisitor vis(q);
    boost::breadth_first_search(g, s, boost::visitor(vis));
    while (!vis.visited.empty()) {
        std::cout << vis.visited.front() << std::endl;
        vis.visited.pop();
    }
}
```

which will output

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

---

**Note** — Boost expects the graph to start at vertex `0`, not `1` - hence the line

```cpp
boost::add_edge(0,1,6,g);
```

if you start at vertex `1` there will be no output.