# Error while defining the predicate for thrust Min_element, using zip_iterators for device_ptr

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust

In the simple example I tried to find the min value, which is not yet visited.

```
float *cost=NULL;
cudaMalloc( (void **) &cost, 5 * sizeof(float) );

bool *visited=NULL;
cudaMalloc( (void **) &visited, 5 * sizeof(bool) );

thrust::device_ptr< float > dp_cost( cost );
thrust::device_ptr< bool > dp_visited( visited );

typedef thrust::device_ptr<bool>  BoolIterator;
typedef thrust::device_ptr<float>  ValueIterator;

BoolIterator bools_begin = dp_visited, bools_end = dp_visited +5;
ValueIterator values_begin = dp_cost, values_end = dp_cost +5; 


typedef thrust::tuple<BoolIterator, ValueIterator> IteratorTuple;
typedef thrust::tuple<bool, float> DereferencedIteratorTuple;
typedef thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> NodePropIterator;

struct nodeProp_comp : public thrust::binary_function<DereferencedIteratorTuple, DereferencedIteratorTuple, bool>
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()( const DereferencedIteratorTuple lhs, const DereferencedIteratorTuple rhs ) const 
    {
        if( !( thrust::get<0>( lhs ) ) && !( thrust::get<0>( rhs ) ) )
        {
            return ( thrust::get<1>( lhs ) < thrust::get<1>( rhs ) );
        }
        else
        {
            return !( thrust::get<0>( lhs ) );
        }
    }
};


NodePropIterator iter_begin (thrust::make_tuple(bools_begin, values_begin));
NodePropIterator iter_end   (thrust::make_tuple(bools_end, values_end));

NodePropIterator min_el_pos = thrust::min_element( iter_begin, iter_end, nodeProp_comp() );

DereferencedIteratorTuple tmp = *min_el_pos;
```

But on compilation i get this error.

thrust_min.cu(99): error: no instance of overloaded function "thrust::min_element" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (NodePropIterator, NodePropIterator, nodeProp_comp)

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00005c8e_00000000-6_thrust_min.cpp1.ii".

I compile using :

nvcc -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -G -g thrust_min.cu -Xcompiler -rdynamic,-Wall,-Wextra -lineinfo -o thrust_min

I am using gcc version 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC), CUDA 5.

I get no error if I omit the predicate during the call to min_element ... which uses the default 'less' functor i guess.

Please help.

Comment: As an aside, [you should not compile thrust code](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Debugging) with `-G`.  Also, the gcc version you list is not officially one of the [supported versions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#supported-operating-systems).  While I think it's unlikely, it's  remotely possible that this could be the source of the compile issue.  If you provide a complete, compilable example of your issue, I can do a test compile for you.

Comment: @RobertCrovella , thanks for the info. I am new to cuda. anyways here's a link to a small program in pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/ex6UfPVZ

Comment: I was able to reproduce the compile error.  I cannot say precisely why yet, but if I move the struct definition to before `main` as I have done [here](http://pastebin.com/1XdHghz8), the compile error goes away.

Comment: @RobertCrovella ,appreciate your help mate, but i have to use it in a much larger (multifile) program, and even keeping all the declarations outside the calling function, doesn't help. Do you think it's a bug in nvcc/thrust or is it due to the incompatablity with gcc ?

Comment: When you compile the code I provided (only), do you get the error or not?

Comment: @RobertCrovella yes, moving the declarations+struct definition out of main solves it for this small program.

Comment: Well, I realize it's tedious, but it would be useful if you can provide a reproducer example for the larger, multifile case.  Is it simply that you have other files with these struct definitions that are inside of main?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I will try to do it. In the mean time I am thinking maybe I'll keep those def-s in a header and try to insert them before main, and see what happens. 

The structure of my program is : I have a main file (from where i call a bunch of cuda kernels and normal cpp functions). Each of those are spread out over their own files. The above 'logic' is in it's own .cu file and gets compiled it with the rest. But putting the def-s above the function that uses it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked around about this, and it seems that, in c++03, a local type (i.e., `nodeProp`) can't be used as a template parameter because it has no linkage.  You may want to review this (non-thrust related) [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751977/local-type-as-template-arguments-in-c) for additional discussion.

Thrust, being a template library, depends on this.  So I think the recommendation is to put your functors that are used in thrust operations at global scope.

If you think there are other issues at play, you may want to post a new question with examples.  However for the code you've posted in this question, I believe this is the reason, and I've demonstrated that [reordering the code](http://pastebin.com/1XdHghz8) fixes the issue.  Note the struct definition is really what is at issue here, not the typedefs.