# error C2784 ,class in key map

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, keymaps

I have a problem with the container map. I need to store my own class Person  in key but i have error C2784 (i.e., "The compiler cannot determine a template argument from the supplied function arguments."). It's example from the book "Ivor Horton's beginning Visual C++ 2010"

```
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    class Person{
     public:
     string c_name,c_surname;
     Person(string name,string surname){
     c_name=name;
     c_surname=surname;
        }
    };

     map<Person,string> phonebook;

     phonebook.insert(make_pair(Person("Mel","GIBSON"),"24 32 23"));
     phonebook[Person("Mel2","Gibson2")]="243 32 23";

      /* it doesn`t work too
     typedef pair<Person,string> Entry;
     Entry entry1= Entry(Person("Jack","Jones"),"213 567 1234");

     phonebook.insert(entry1);*/

    system("Pause");
}
```

Error   1   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const main::Person' e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional  125 1   AllClasses

Error   2   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'const main::Person'   e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional  125 1   AllClasses

Error   3   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const main::Person'   e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional  125 1   AllClasses

Error   4   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const main::Person'   e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional  125 1   AllClasses

Error   5   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const main::Person'  e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional  125 1   AllClasses

Error   6   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const main::Person'    e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional  125 1   AllClasses

Error   7   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const main::Person'  e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional  125 1   AllClasses

Error   8   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const main::Person'    e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional  125 1   AllClasses

Error   9   error C2676: binary '<' : 'const main::Person' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator    e:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional  125 1   AllClasses

Comment: For those of us that doesn't know what "error C2784" is, please copy the ***complete and unedited error log*** into your question. In fact, when asking questions about any compiler or linker error, please always do that.

Comment: one part of the error is due to this (local type used in templates): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751977/local-type-as-template-arguments-in-c Fix it by moving definition of `Person` outside main.

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 you could not use local classes (classes defined within functions) as template arguments.

In C++11 you can.

So one fix is to update the compiler (there is Visual C++ 2013), and another fix is to move the class definition out of `main`.

---

By the way, **`void main`** is invalid as standard C++, and as standard C, and it's more to type than standard `int main`. If your book has `void main`, then that's a very ungood book. Microsoft's examples that include `void main` are also very ungood.

---

Also, by the way, the

```
system("Pause");
```

at the end is also very ungood practice because

- it is not necessary, has no advantage, but
- it makes the program more difficult to use and has some other problems, and to top it all,
- it's Windows-specific, non-portable code.

To run a console program so that it stops at the end

- in Visual Studio use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, or
- in Visual Studio place a **breakpoint** at the end of `main` (just click in the left margin) and run it with debugging (e.g. via keypress <kbd>F5</kbd>), or
- run it from a command interpreter.

---

**UPDATE**: the now added error messages (even the first one) mention `operator<`. You need to define that also. That is, define an `operator<` function for your class `Person`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip use Ctrl + F5.And about local classes it's interesting. Before that, I always used a pause. :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) requires your keys to be comparable with the `<` operator. Custom structures/classes are not that by default, you need to make a custom `operator<` for comparison.

Comment: Yes , i fixed by using overloaded operator <. And it was in book (full code) after examples, my fold that i didn't see it. Ur answer very help me. Thank you.